# Transforming distinct value quantities into columns in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+--------------------+------------------------+
|            category|count(DISTINCT category)|
+--------------------+------------------------+
|             FINANCE|                       1|
|              ARCADE|                       1|
|     AUTO & VEHICLES|                       1|
```

And would like to transform it in a dataframe like this:

```
+--------------------+------------------------+
|            FINANCE | ARCADE | AUTO & VEHICLES|
+--------------------+------------------------+
|            1       |   1    |      1        |
```

But I can't think in any way of doing that except the very brute-force python way I am sure will be very inefficient. Is there a smarted way of doing that using pyspark operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pivot()` function and then use `first` for aggregation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupby().pivot("category").agg(first("count(DISTINCT category)")).show()
+------+---------------+-------+                                                
|ARCADE|AUTO & VEHICLES|FINANCE|
+------+---------------+-------+
|     1|              1|      1|
+------+---------------+-------+
```